# What is a 'star rose'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading a book and encountered the words *star rose*. What does it mean? The context is listed below.

> As JavaScript’s **star rose**, discontent came from all corners. Some pointed
>   to its numerous little quirks and inconsistencies. Others complained about
>   its lack of classes and inheritance. And a new generation of coders, who
>   had cut their teeth on Ruby and Python, were stymied by its thickets of
>   curly braces, parentheses, and semicolons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As JavaScript’s star rose

This means "as Javascript became more popular."

*Rose* is the past tense of *rise*, and not the flower. Javascript is becoming a [rising star](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/rising%20star), i.e. more popular.

Comment: I disagree with this unless it was written as an awkward metaphor. Star as a noun is not a synonym for popularity.

Comment: No, it shares the metaphor of "His star is in the ascendant".

Comment: @tenfour, This is a common idiom.  Google "star is rising" for the more usual form.  "Star rose" is a perfectly acceptable past tense formulation.

Comment: I stand corrected

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be seen as a single phrase "star rose", which seems to imply the rose of a star, but rather, "rose" as the verb, and "star" as the noun.

"Star" here refers to the popularity and fame of Javascript. "Rose" refers to the fact that the popularity and fame of Javascript is *increasing* ("Rose" as in "rise" past tense). Thus, read:

> As Javascript's fame increased (star rose)

I hope that helps.